# How to insert record into database using loop

Tags: php, oracle

This is my code:

```
[G_TEST_CC] = {COST_CENTER};
[G_TEST_PLANT] = {PLANT};
header("Location: ../83211_TEST_PM_MONTH/83211_TEST_PM_MONTH.php");

$MONTH = array();

$MONTH[ 1 ] = 'JAN';
$MONTH[ 2 ] = 'FEB';
$MONTH[ 3 ] = 'MAR';
$MONTH[ 4 ] = 'APR';
$MONTH[ 5 ] = 'MAY';
$MONTH[ 6 ] = 'JUN';
$MONTH[ 7 ] = 'JUL';
$MONTH[ 8 ] = 'AUG';
$MONTH[ 9 ] = 'SEP';
$MONTH[ 10 ] = 'OCT';
$MONTH[ 11 ] = 'NOV';
$MONTH[ 12 ] = 'DEC';


for($i = 1; $i<=12 ; $i++){ 


sc_lookup(dataset, "select max(ID) from CMS.SUM_TEST");

$MAXID = {dataset[0][0]};
$NEWMAXID = $MAXID + $i;


// SQL statement parameters
$insert_table  = 'EXPENSE_TEST_PM';      // Table name
$insert_fields = array(   // Field list, add as many as needed
     'ID' => "'$NEWMAXID'",
     'BUDGET_YEAR' => "'[GLOBAL_BUDGETYEAR]'",
    'VERSION' => "'[GLOBAL_VERSION]'",
    'PLANT' => "'[G_TEST_PLANT]'",
    'COST_CENTER' => "'[G_TEST_CC]'",
    'MONTH' => "'$MONTH[$i]'",
 );

// Insert record
$insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $insert_table
    . ' ('   . implode(', ', array_keys($insert_fields))   . ')'
    . ' VALUES ('    . implode(', ', array_values($insert_fields)) . ')';

sc_exec_sql($insert_sql);

}
```

I want to add many records depending on PLANT and COST CENTER but i only got 12 records even if I submit different PLANT and COST CENTER.

This images may help understand the issue:
[image: Choosing PLANT and COST CENTER]
[image: EXPENSE_TEST_PM table]

Comment: As your loop will perform till i=12 so you get only 12 insert

Comment: I used only 12 because of the month, How can I saved 12 record per PLANT and COST CENTER?

Comment: NEVER use string concatenation to include parameters into SQL: use parameters instead (or show evidence of whitelisting values: but that is harder to do). The ongoing occurrence SQL Injection is embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

As Dipanwita Kundu said, your loop will stop after 12 iterations. If you want more insertions, you probably need to add one or two loops inside the first one to get your values.
I also recommand you to do only one insert request, not one by iteration, and to not use string concatenation. Something like that :

```
// set fields
$fields = ['ID', 'BUDGET_YEAR', 'VERSION', 'PLANT', 'COST_CENTER', 'MONTH'];

// set max id
sc_lookup(dataset, "select max(ID) from CMS.SUM_TEST");
$id = {dataset[0][0]};

// set sql
$insert_table  = 'EXPENSE_TEST_PM';      // Table name
$insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $insert_table . ' ('   . implode(', ', $fields)   . ') VALUES ';

for($i = 1; $i<=12 ; $i++){ 

    // you need to add new loop(s) here to get every data from active month
    // it depends on your variables format
    // here I assume that your PLANT and COST_CENTER are indexed by month
    // for (...) // loop for cost center
        // for (...) loop for plant
            // SQL statement parameters
            $insert_sql .= '('
                . $id
                . '{GLOBAL_BUDGETYEAR[0][0]}'
                . '{GLOBAL_VERSION[0][0]}'
                . '{PLANT[' . $i . '][' . $plantIndex. ']})'
                . '{COST_CENTER[' . $i . '][' . $costCenterIndex . ']})'
                . $i
                . '),';
            $id++;

        // }
    // } // end new loop
}
// remove last ","
$insert_sql = trim($insert_sql, ',');

// Insert records
sc_exec_sql($insert_sql);
```